# how can i add js to geb locator?

Tags: groovy, geb

After this code I have error:

```
gebLocator(wait: true) { $("a#fCoverage") }
browser.js.exec(gebLocator+ ".addEventListener('click', function(){alert('GTM')});")
```

Error message:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.plus() is applicable for argument
>   types: (java.lang.String) values: [.addEventListener('click',
>   function(){alert('GTM')});] Possible solutions:
>   plus(geb.navigator.Navigator), has(java.lang.String),
>   is(java.lang.String), last(), value(), add(java.lang.String)

Comment: `def "blablabla"(array2){
   def map = arra1
  
   System.println(map.getClass())//=class java.util.ArrayList
   
  for (i in 0..array2.size()){
  
   assert map[i].equals(array2[i])  
  }
  
  return true    
  }`

Comment: Can you explain what your goal is that isn't met by list1.containsAll(list2). Are you in a unit test and need to know which elements are missing?

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that you have tried to execute method `plus(String)` on `NonEmptyNavigator` what is impossible because `NonEmptyNavigator` doesn't have such a method.

If you want to execute js code using geb driver:

```
browser.js.exec("document.getElementById('fCoverage').addEventListener('click', function(){alert('GTM')});")
```

Comment: Or `browser.driver.executeScript(object + ".addEventListener('click', function(){alert('GTM')});")`

Comment: object - gebLocator(wait: true) { $("a#fCoverage") }